# What's a phrase or word that describe acting, writing and directing at the same time?

Tags: phrase-requests

Some actors write their own scripts, direct their own films and act in their own films at the same time. Is there a word or a phrase for it?

The best I can come up with is self-scripted play, much like a child playing with toys.

Comment: Why  would there be? A self-scripted play? Plays are scripted? Hmm. One writes a play, one does not script one.

Comment: Triple threat? Multi-threat talent? Multi-talented?

Comment: Written, directed, and performed by ...  For example: http://capitalcriticscircle.com/the-anderson-project-conceived-written-directed-and-performed-by-robert-lepage/

Comment: First as Lambie asked, why would there be?

Even if there should be, where is your research?

As it is, have you not made "a child playing with toys" a pretty-good description of your Question?

Comment: Are you looking for a term to describe the play or the three aspects (acting, writing and directing) in general?

Comment: When someone writes and directs, they are called *writer-director*. There is no such established term for someone who also acts, because it is rare.